# Compare multiple columns from same table and only report if any of the columns have different values

Tags: sql, join

I've got a table called Price table and trying to write a select query to fetch records only when one of the columns - Price or Fromdate or Todate or Packsize is different between store region's = Metro and Regional.

How is such a query implemented?

[image]

The expected output in this case is
[image]

Comment: Surely you must have something to show for your hours try? Put the code you have written so we can see where you're going wrong and know how to teach you better. We're not a "do my homework for me" service, and it helps us know we're not being treated thus if we see your efforts so far

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help] Show what you are able to do. Research before considering asking & reflect research in a question. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `COUNT()` as an analytic function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Price, Fromdate, Todate, Packsize) cnt
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT StoreRegion, Itemid, Price, Fromdate, Todate, Packsize
FROM cte
WHERE cnt = 1;
```